# timer_t in <ctime> for cygwin?

Tags: c++, cygwin

In the following code, when runs on cygwin on Windows 7,

```
#include<ctime>
#ifdef _WINDOWS
    HANDLE           m_timer;
    bool             m_first;
#elif defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__)
    // Mac OS X
    pthread_t        m_thread_id;
    pthread_attr_t   m_attributes;
    unsigned         m_interval;    
    pthread_cond_t   m_condition_var;
#else
    // Linux
    static void *   g_timer;
    void            (*m_old_handler)(int);
    void *          m_old_timer;
    timer_t         m_timerid;
#endif
```

it throws me error

```
error: 'timer_t' does not name a type
     timer_t         m_timerid;
```

How should I address it?

Answer (score 1):

The type `timer_t` is defined in the `<sys/types.h>` header, [as specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html).

Add

```
#include <sys/types.h>
```

(And you probably don't need `#include <ctime>`, unless you're using `time_t` or `clock_t` elsewhere in your code.)